# How to get row index of selected DataGridView Windows element row in Gherkin testing?

Tags: c#, winforms, testing, datagridview, gherkin

I am testing a C# WinForms app in Gherkin, using Appium and SpecFlow. I have a problem with getting the index of selected row. I don't know how to do it.

My goal in this task is to check if the cell in selected row and column "State" is "finished" or "in progress". It has to be "in progress" in this test case.

I hardcoded index values and it works but I would like to do it the right way:

```
 [When(@"user selects a mission that is still in progress")]
        public void WhenUserSelectsAMissionThatIsStillInProgress()
        {
            var driver = GuiDriver.GetOrCreateDriver();
            var dgvMissions = driver.FindElementByAccessibilityId("dtgListaMissions");
            var row = dgvMissions.FindElement(By.Name($"Row 0"));
            var cell = row.FindElement(By.Name($"State Row 0")).Text;

            Assert.AreEqual("in progress", cell); // true
        }
```

In properties panel, DataGridView has dtgListaMissions as (Name). In Accessibility Insights for Windows I can see that every cell in that column is called State row and then number (index). Every row is called Row and then number (LegacyIAccessiblePattern.Name    = Row 1).